# Loop that doesn't end

Tags: java

Here is a piece from my code.
My problem is that this line `System.out.println(digit.contains(0));` prints false even when there is a zero in the list "digit".

```
    int x = 5;
    int y = 0;
    int z;
    ArrayList<Character> digit = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] new_digit = {};
    boolean end_loop = true;

    do {
        z = x * y;
        new_digit = ("" + z).toCharArray();
        for (int k = 0; k < new_digit.length; k++) {
            if (!digit.contains(new_digit[k])) {
                digit.add(new_digit[k]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(digit.contains(0));
```

what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is a list of characters:

```
ArrayList<Character> digit = new ArrayList<>();
```

You are checking whether it contains the integer zero:

```
digit.contains(0)
```

Because this is an integer and not a character, it will will be *implicitly* converted to the ASCII character represented by that number, [which is NULL](http://www.asciitable.com/). The character 0 is represented in ASCII by the integer 48.

If you want to check whether your list contains the *character* zero, do this:

```
digit.contains('0')
```